# how to check which version of numpy scipy depends on?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, dependencies

I'm installing scipy and already have numpy installed. How can I know if my numpy version is sufficient for scipy 0.15.1?

Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use `test` in `numpy` and `scipy`

```
    import numpy
    import scipy

    numpy.test("full")
    scipy.test("full")
```

I hope these may help you!